# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<Customer>'

Tags: angular, http, get

I have a setup like this

- api.service (wraps the httpClient Module)
- customer.service

the api service get looks like this:

```
get<T>(url: string, options?) {
return this.httpClient.get<T>(this.apiUrl + url, this.getOptions(options));}
```

in my customer.service I have:

```
    private fetchCustomer(access_token: String): Observable<Customer> {
      const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token }) };
      return this.http
        .get<Customer>('customers/me', options)
        .map(res => {
          const customer = res.data;
          customer.access_token = access_token;
          return customer;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }
```

and it give me this error:

```
[ts]
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<Customer>'.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'.
```

Comment: In your fetchCustomer method does this.http refer to your api service? or the http client

Comment: it uses my api service

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use the new way of getting the json data....

```
const customer = res['data'];
```

Comment: that should be identical to const customer = res.data; Maybe that format is bypassing the typescript compiler error

Comment: hmm.. could be... but if the docs says res['data'] then I assume that it´s for a reason ;)

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the angular source code (v4.3.3), when you wrap the http.get without specifying the type of `options` the typescript compiler is using this type definition

```
/**
 * Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns the full event stream.
 *
 * @return an `Observable` of all `HttpEvent`s for the request, with a body type of `T`.
 */
get<T>(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe: 'events';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;
```

To get the typescript compiler to use the correct type definition, you can specify that the options is of type Object. In your case the getOptions method should specify it is returning the type Object.

```
get<T>(url: string, options?) {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(
        this.apiUrl + url, 
        this.getOptions(options) // this.getOptions needs to specify it is returning the type Object
    );
}

getOptions(options): Object {...}
```

Now the typescript compiler will find the correct type definition

```
/**
 * Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns it.
 *
 * @return an `Observable` of the body as type `T`.
 */
get<T>(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<T>;
```

and finally now you can access data

```
const customer = res.data;
```

Answer (score 7):

The new HttpClient in Angular 4.3 has currently 3 protoypes for `get<T>`

They are

```
get<T>(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe: 'events';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>;

get<T>(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe: 'response';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpResponse<T>>;

get<T>(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<T>;
```

The Comments at the top of client.d.ts state this.

```
 * Each request method has multiple signatures, and the return type varies according to which
 * signature is called (mainly the values of `observe` and `responseType`).
```

The really important part is the observe parameter

`get<T>(url, {observe: 'events'})` returns `HttpEvent<T>`

`get<T>(url, {observe: 'response'})` returns `HttpResponse<T>`

`get<T>(url, {observe: 'body'})` returns `T`

---

**Note**: if you subclass the options part into a method you must return a type of Object, without that the compiler will automatically select the first method which happens to return `HttpEvent<T>`

so

```
getOptions(): any {
    return { observe: 'body' }
};
```

and

```
getOptions(): any {
    return { observe: 'response' }
};
```

will compile to the **wrong** interface and return `HttpEvent<T>`, but

```
getOptions(): object {
    return { observe: 'body'}
};
```

and

```
getOptions(): object {
    return { observe: 'response'}
};
```

will return `T` and `HttpResponse<T>` respectively

Comment: Why does it automatically select the first method signature unless you specify type of `Object`?

Comment: This is a good answer, it seems as though the options should always be passed to http methods to ensure the correct parsing with responseType and the right types are used.