# Typescript Error When Getting HTTP Options from Angular Service

Tags: angular, typescript, http-get

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET request using Angular 4 and HttpClient/HttpHeaders from @angular/common/http. Here is what my request looks like:

```
getPhysicians() {
  let queryURL, queryOptions;

  queryURL = "http://path/to/our/backend/pathologists";

  queryOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    withCredentials: true
  };

  let request = this.http.get<any[]>(queryURL, queryOptions);

  request.subscribe(
    data => {
      data.forEach((physician) => { // no problems here
        // some logic with the response items
      })
    },

    err =>  {
      console.log("Error retrieving physicians");
    }
  );
}
```

This code works fine. However, my partner and I have decided that we don't need to include some of this information in every component and have decided to make a query building service. Here's what that looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class QueryBuilderService {

  baseURL: string = "http://path/to/our/backend/"

  requestOptions: any = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    withCredentials: true
  };

  constructor() { }

  getRequestOptions() {
    return this.requestOptions;
  }

  getAllPhysiciansQuery() {
    return this.baseURL + "pathologists";
  }
}
```

And the adjusted code in the component injecting the service looks like this:

```
getPhysicians() {
  let queryURL, queryOptions;

  queryURL = this.queryBuilderService.getAllPhysiciansQuery();

  queryOptions = this.queryBuilderService.getRequestOptions();

  let request = this.http.get<any[]>(queryURL, queryOptions);

  request.subscribe(
    data => {
      data.forEach((physician) => { // this line now throws a compilation error
        // some logic with the response items
      })
    },

    err =>  {
      console.log("Error retrieving physicians");
    }
  );
}
```

We are returning the same exact values as before, but now from this service. However, we now get a TypeScript error on the "data" function parameter stating

```
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<any[]>'. 
Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'.
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why we are getting an error if we are returning the same exact values. Why is the type not coming back as any[] anymore? I have verified that the queryURL parameter works, regardless of whether it is created in getPhysicians or pulled from the QueryBuilderService. It is the options that is causing this typing issue.

**EDIT**
Here is what is returned when we make the call the original way:
[image: This is all just test data, not true sensitive information.]
Note, this is all just test data. No real sensitive information here.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what does your data look like?  Can you console.log it?

Comment: @Farasi78 I edited the description to have a screenshot of that information.

Comment: Hey, can you console log the data from the response when you use the second method?  I think if you remove the forEach loop you should still be able to console log the raw response.  I think it might be creating an array of type any with an array so you would need something like data[0].forEach.... just guessing, would be easier if you could log it...

Comment: @Farasi78 I tried that and I got the same exact response as the first method.

Comment: You are using a `get` request with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek That did the trick. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes, sorry I'm kind of new so I'm not sure if that's the best way. I assumed that's what I had to do if I want to append URL arguments to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to @GreyBeardedGeek I have found my solution. I needed to explicitly declare a return type of Object to my getRequestOptions() function. Essentially, without knowing specifically that the function is returning a type of Object, it will default to the HttpEvent type. More information can be found in this link:

[Property 'data' does not exist on type 'HttpEvent<Customer>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698594/property-data-does-not-exist-on-type-httpeventcustomer)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient):

> The `responseType` value determines how a successful response body will be parsed. If `responseType` is the default `json`, a type interface for the resulting object may be passed as a type parameter to `request()`.

I'm honestly not sure what was changed between your first and second attempt that would break it, but you are getting `HttpEvent` as the response. You can change this in a few ways:

1. Add `responseType: 'json'` to the requestOptions
2. Add `observe: 'body'` to the requestOptions
3. Update your `.subscribe` callback to handle HttpEvent, e.g.

```
request.subscribe((event: HttpEvent) => {
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.response) {
    event.body.forEach(physician => { /* logic */ });
  }
},
```

Based on the other comments and answers, you should also use `requestOptions: Object` instead of `requestOptions: any` and/or update `getRequestOptions` to return type of `Object`.