# HttpParams use with Put and Post change return type to Observable<HttpEvent<T>> in Angular 6

Tags: angular, observable, angular6

I have a scenario where i am doing a post and it gives me back a json object as well.

When using URL and body only in post, the return type is `Observable<T>`

but when using params with it as well, the return type becomes `Observable<HttpEvent<T>>`

Here is a simple example...

info to post

```
let someInfo: SomeInfo = new SomeInfo("abc", "xyz");
```

The return type expected after the post is MwUser.

Regular Post without params

```
this.httpclient.post<MwUser>(apiUrl, someInfo).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

And res is MwUser

[image]

Now doing the same post with params

```
const paramToPass: any = new HttpParams().set('groupType', 'xyz');
this.httpclient.post<MwUser>(apiUrl, someInfo, paramToPass).subscribe(
  res => {
    user = res;
    console.log(res);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

and here res is not MwUser

[image]

How to handle this second scenario (above) to change res to MwUser and still pass the params?

side note: when we pass the params to the get, the return type is `Observable<T>`.

Comment: Remove `any` from `const paramToPass = new HttpParams().set('groupType', 'xyz');` The return type of `http.post()` depends on the type of `paramToPass` parameter.

Comment: @AmitChigadani nt following the second part regarding the return type in your comment. Could you please elaborate on that? All i want is Observable<T> in this case. I have already changed the code base where the model to pass will have every thing, which should have been the case from the get go.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698594/property-data-does-not-exist-on-type-httpeventcustomer/46239941#46239941 to understand different variants of `http.post()` request. There are multiple signatures (overloaded) for the same method `http.post()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `observe : 'body';` to the third parameter, which is `httpOptions` (in your case `paramToPass`) to expect the return type `Observable<T>`. You might check official docs to see different variants of [http.post](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

```
let paramToPass = {};
paramToPass['params'] = new HttpParams().set('groupType', 'xyz');
paramToPass['observe'] = 'body';

this.httpclient.post<MwUser>(apiUrl, someInfo, paramToPass).subscribe(
  res => {
    user = res;
    console.log(res);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: This is resulting in `'HttpParams' has no properties in common with type '{ header?: HttpHeaders | { [header:string]: string | string[];} observe?: "body"; params?:...`

Comment: I still have a long way to go learning Angular, Its been only two weeks at my end working with this technology.

Comment: It will certainly take time to learn new things. Happy learning!!

Comment: Was trying to take a look a the GET, now above is resulting in `?params=groupType=xyz&observe=body:`, which then result in no action found. Why this construct? Where as on get `const paramToPass = new HttpParams().set('groupType', 'xyz');` works fine/

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the HttEvent to MwUser, there are some examples here: https://angular.io/guide/http.

Look for .pipe(

Comment: Infact i am confused on the map part. Also, do i need to use tap?

Comment: I dont think tap is necessary

Comment: this one looks like what you need

return this.http.request(req).pipe(
  map(event => this.getEventMessage(event, file)),
  tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
  last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
  catchError(this.handleError(file))
);

Comment: I have been playing with this piece but still no luck